# Передача массива строк в функцию

Tags: c++

Что не так в этом коде?
Подскажите, где ошибка?

```
#include <iostream>  
using namespace std;

void EditName(char chName[1]);

int main()  
{  
    char *chName[1];  
    chName[0] = "Bill";  
    EditName(chName[1]);  
    cout << chName[0];  
    return 0;
}

void EditName(char chName[1])  
{  
    chName[0] = "Name";
```

}

И, если кто знает, где можно почитать про вопрос о массивах, они меня устали :)

Answer (score 3):

Ну, это не скомпилируется. У вас какой аргумент функции `EditName`? `char[1]` -- строка длиной 1. То есть `chName[0]` -- это её первый символ.

А вы в первый символ записываете целую другую строку, что делать несчастному компилятору?

Обратите внимание, что в функции `main` `chName` -- это таки массив строк, а вот в функции `EditName` `chName` объявлен вами как просто строка из одного символа. Это вас не путает?

(Там ещё другие ошибки есть.)